# Mocking BehaviourSubject in a service and use in component

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I am writing unit test cases which are required for one of the component in the Angular application. This component is using one shared service and this service contains two newly added behaviour subjects as fields.

Now I am trying to adjust the unit test cases (which are written in Jest) for the existing component. Here, I am getting errors in the unit test cases as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined`.

I am unable to understand how to mock or spy or create stub for these newly added behaviour subject fields.

`MyComponent.ts`

```
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    componentField: any;
    constructor(
        private myService: MyService) {
      }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.componentField = this.myService.mySubject$.getValue();
    if(this.componentField) {
    console.log('this.componentField values are ::', this.componentField.value);
    }
    }
    
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.myService.mySubject$.next(null);
     }
    }
```

`Service.ts`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
public mySubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

fillSubject() {
const value = {'name':'ABC', 'value':'XYZ'}
this.mySubject$.next(value);
}
}
```

`MyComponent.spec.ts`

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
let component: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
let myServiceMock: Partial<MyService>;
let service: MyService

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]), HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: '$rootScope', useValue: {} },
        { provide: 'User', useValue: {} },
        { provide: MyService, useValue: myServiceMock },
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

When I executed `npm run test --main /path/to/MyComponent.spec.ts` I am getting error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined`. I think I am not mocking or creating spy which is required for behaviour subject in the service. I tried to search any references in Google, but I am not getting correct way.

Comment: You _define_ the mock service variable, `let myServiceMock: Partial<MyService>`, but don't actually give it a _value_ anywhere. There's no _implementation_; `{ provide: MyService, useValue: myServiceMock }` is injecting the value `undefined`.

Comment: Along the lines of what jonsharpe stated, it's unclear what your test code is. I recommend you rename your modules with the word 'test' in them to clearly specify what should be getting the mock, and who is responsible for initializing everything you need for those tests to run. That level of organization alone might have avoided this error.